# Android: IcyStreamMeta - App crashes after stream title changes

Tags: java, android

I'm using the IcyStreamMeta.class for retreiving metadata. This is the IcyStreamMeta.class

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class IcyStreamMeta {

    protected URL streamUrl;
    private Map<String, String> metadata;
    private boolean isError;

    public IcyStreamMeta(URL streamUrl) {
        setStreamUrl(streamUrl);

        isError = false;
    }

    /**
     * Get artist using stream's title
     *
     * @return String
     * @throws IOException
     */
    public String getArtist() throws IOException {
        Map<String, String> data = getMetadata();

        if (!data.containsKey("StreamTitle"))
            return "";

        String streamTitle = data.get("StreamTitle");
        String title = streamTitle.substring(0, streamTitle.indexOf("-"));
        return title.trim();
    }

    /**
     * Get title using stream's title
     *
     * @return String
     * @throws IOException
     */
    public String getTitle() throws IOException {
        Map<String, String> data = getMetadata();

        if (!data.containsKey("StreamTitle"))
            return "";

        String streamTitle = data.get("StreamTitle");
        String artist = streamTitle.substring(streamTitle.indexOf("-")+1);
        return artist.trim();
    }

    public Map<String, String> getMetadata() throws IOException {
        if (metadata == null) {
            refreshMeta();
        }

        return metadata;
    }

    public void refreshMeta() throws IOException {
        retreiveMetadata();
    }

    private void retreiveMetadata() throws IOException {
        URLConnection con = streamUrl.openConnection();
        con.setRequestProperty("Icy-MetaData", "1");
        con.setRequestProperty("Connection", "close");
        con.setRequestProperty("Accept", null);
        con.connect();

        int metaDataOffset = 0;
        Map<String, List<String>> headers = con.getHeaderFields();
        InputStream stream = con.getInputStream();

        if (headers.containsKey("icy-metaint")) {
            // Headers are sent via HTTP
            metaDataOffset = Integer.parseInt(headers.get("icy-metaint").get(0));
        } else {
            // Headers are sent within a stream
            StringBuilder strHeaders = new StringBuilder();
            char c;
            while ((c = (char)stream.read()) != -1) {
                strHeaders.append(c);
                if (strHeaders.length() > 5 && (strHeaders.substring((strHeaders.length() - 4), strHeaders.length()).equals("\r\n\r\n"))) {
                    // end of headers
                    break;
                }
            }

            // Match headers to get metadata offset within a stream
            Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\r\\n(icy-metaint):\\s*(.*)\\r\\n");
            Matcher m = p.matcher(strHeaders.toString());
            if (m.find()) {
                metaDataOffset = Integer.parseInt(m.group(2));
            }
        }

        // In case no data was sent
        if (metaDataOffset == 0) {
            isError = true;
            return;
        }

        // Read metadata
        int b;
        int count = 0;
        int metaDataLength = 4080; // 4080 is the max length
        boolean inData = false;
        StringBuilder metaData = new StringBuilder();
        // Stream position should be either at the beginning or right after headers
        while ((b = stream.read()) != -1) {
            count++;

            // Length of the metadata
            if (count == metaDataOffset + 1) {
                metaDataLength = b * 16;
            }

            if (count > metaDataOffset + 1 && count < (metaDataOffset + metaDataLength)) {              
                inData = true;
            } else {                
                inData = false;             
            }               
            if (inData) {               
                if (b != 0) {                   
                    metaData.append((char)b);               
                }           
            }               
            if (count > (metaDataOffset + metaDataLength)) {
                break;
            }

        }

        // Set the data
        metadata = IcyStreamMeta.parseMetadata(metaData.toString());

        // Close
        stream.close();
    }

    public boolean isError() {
        return isError;
    }

    public URL getStreamUrl() {
        return streamUrl;
    }

    public void setStreamUrl(URL streamUrl) {
        this.metadata = null;
        this.streamUrl = streamUrl;
        this.isError = false;
    }

    public static Map<String, String> parseMetadata(String metaString) {
        Map<String, String> metadata = new HashMap();
        String[] metaParts = metaString.split(";");
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^([a-zA-Z]+)=\\'([^\\']*)\\'$");
        Matcher m;
        for (int i = 0; i < metaParts.length; i++) {
            m = p.matcher(metaParts[i]);
            if (m.find()) {
                metadata.put((String)m.group(1), (String)m.group(2));
            }
        }

        return metadata;
    }
}
```

I'm using in my MainActivity this method to get the metadata and to update the textbox

```
private void getMeta()
    {
        Timer timer = new Timer();
        timer.schedule(new TimerTask()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                try
                {
                    IcyStreamMeta icy   = new IcyStreamMeta(new URL("http://176.28.31.39:8000"));
                    data                = icy.getArtist() + " - " + icy.getTitle();


                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable()
                    {
                         public void run()
                         {
                             textbox.setText(data);
                         }
                    });
                }
                catch (MalformedURLException e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                catch (IOException e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        },0,5000);
    }
```

It works perfectly fine for the current stream title + artist, but whenever the song finishes and starts a new one my app crashes. Why does this happen? Can anyone help me?

EDIT: I'm getting this Error:

```
 09-23 14:57:46.095: E/AndroidRuntime(17321): FATAL EXCEPTION: Timer-0
09-23 14:57:46.095: E/AndroidRuntime(17321): java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=15; regionStart=0; regionLength=-1
09-23 14:57:46.095: E/AndroidRuntime(17321):    at java.lang.String.startEndAndLength(String.java:593)
09-23 14:57:46.095: E/AndroidRuntime(17321):    at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1474)
09-23 14:57:46.095: E/AndroidRuntime(17321):    at com.example.alifberadio.IcyStreamMeta.getArtist(IcyStreamMeta.java:38)
09-23 14:57:46.095: E/AndroidRuntime(17321):    at com.example.alifberadio.MainActivity$2.run(MainActivity.java:295)
09-23 14:57:46.095: E/AndroidRuntime(17321):    at java.util.Timer$TimerImpl.run(Timer.java:284)
```

It redirects me to this code

```
public String getArtist() throws IOException {
        Map<String, String> data = getMetadata();

        if (!data.containsKey("StreamTitle"))
            return "";

        String streamTitle = data.get("StreamTitle");
        String title = streamTitle.substring(0, streamTitle.indexOf("-"));
        return title.trim();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

On a side note, since I can't seem to find the original home of IcyStreamMeta.java I thought I'd post my modified section, to get rid of that HORRIBLE regex, that breaks if the Artist or Title have an apostrophe in them..

```
public static Map<String, String> parseMetadata(String metaString) {
    Map<String, String> metadata = new HashMap();

    String[] metaParts = metaString.split(";");
    for (int i = 0; i < metaParts.length; i++) {
        String part = metaParts[i].substring(0, metaParts[i].indexOf("="));
        String songname = metaParts[i].substring(metaParts[i].indexOf("'")+1, metaParts[i].lastIndexOf("'"));
        metadata.put(part, songname);
    }

    return metadata;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might get that problem when there is no metadata in the stream as some station on shoutcast like In the Mood Music don't send any in their stream. Also, when changing tracks it clears the metadata before the new artists data. So you need to check the data being returned exists.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error once, and it occurred because I was running multiple TimerTasks, and need to kill them off when you activity state changes e.g. getMeta() called from onCreate.

I also found out that IcyStreamMeta gets broken under Android 4.4(codename KitKat) whilst testing my app that uses it .

Answer (score 0):

change from this

```
 public String getArtist() throws IOException {
    Map<String, String> data = getMetadata();

    if (!data.containsKey("StreamTitle"))
        return "";

    String streamTitle = data.get("StreamTitle");
    String title = streamTitle.substring(0, streamTitle.indexOf("-"));
    return title.trim();
}

public String getTitle() throws IOException {
    Map<String, String> data = getMetadata();

    if (!data.containsKey("StreamTitle"))
        return "";

    String streamTitle = data.get("StreamTitle");
    String artist = streamTitle.substring(streamTitle.indexOf("-")+1);
    return artist.trim();
}
```

to this

```
public String getArtist() throws IOException {
    Map<String, String> data = getMetadata();

    if (!data.containsKey("StreamTitle"))
        return "";

    String streamTitle = data.get("StreamTitle");
    String title = streamTitle.length() > 0 ? streamTitle.substring(0, streamTitle.indexOf("-")) : " ";
    return title.trim();
}

public String getTitle() throws IOException {
    Map<String, String> data = getMetadata();

    if (!data.containsKey("StreamTitle"))
        return "";

    String streamTitle = data.get("StreamTitle");
    String artist = streamTitle.length() > 0 ? streamTitle.substring(streamTitle.indexOf("-")+1) : " ";
    return artist.trim();
}
```